# Escaping equals signs, plus sign and slashes from mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm passing a base64 encoded parameter using GET. After converting to base64 I end up with a string that contains slashes, plus and equals signs that break my mod_rewrite rule. My mod_rewrite rule is

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^page/(\w+)$  page.php?code=$1
```

The code parameter is base64. Is there any way to escape those characters automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[B]` flag but i am not sure either

```
RewriteRule ^page/(\w+)$  page.php?code=$1 [B]
```

> The [B] flag instructs RewriteRule to escape non-alphanumeric
>   characters before applying the transformation.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: [B] is exactly what I was looking for. However, I also made a mistake with the regex. \w+ matches a-z0-9 only. The following rule works perfectly        **RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$  page.php?code=$1 [B]**